# Cannot await system.IObservable.*** error in Rx of C#

Tags: c#, system.reactive

The question is simple.  I find this piece of code from the website http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc0 here.

```
 public static async void StartBackgroundWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Shows use of Start to start on a background thread:");
            var o = Observable.Start(() =>
            {
                //This starts on a background thread.
                Console.WriteLine("From background thread. Does not block main thread.");
                Console.WriteLine("Calculating...");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Background work completed.");
            });
            **await o.FirstAsync();**   // subscribe and wait for completion of background operation.  If you remove await, the main thread will complete first.
            Console.WriteLine("Main thread completed.");
        }
```

But when I paste it into my project, an error which says "Cannot await system.IObservable ". What's wrong with it? How can I run this code? Given that I'm not so much familiar with Rx and C#, forgive me if the question is so stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably linking to Rx DLLs for .NET 4.0 and not for .NET 4.5.

If you are getting the package from Nuget, try to reinstall the package using command "Update-Package –reinstall" from Nuget Console. For more information, see: http://docs.nuget.org/consume/reinstalling-packages

You can check the currently used version by going to the Project's Reference/System.Reactive.Core's property tab, and check for the "Path" property. It should contain "net45" as follows:

+++\packages\Rx-Core.2.2.5\lib\net45\System.Reactive.Core.dll

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you say I change the currently used version to Debug45 on the toolbar and I really works. @nikoniko